How to manage time slot selection for weekdays using React and react-hook-form?
I’m building a feature in my React app where users can select time slots based on the day of the week (e.g., Monday, Tuesday, etc.). This is displayed in a table made with MUI - Grid, where the columns are the days of the week and the rows are the time slots.

Is this the most efficient way to handle adding/removing time slots?
How can I ensure the state updates properly for both removing and adding time slots when clicking?
Is there a better approach using react-hook-form for managing such selections?

I have already tried a lot of things, but this isn't working properly. It's only saving the latest selected by row., but if I select another item from the same column, it will "reset" the state and only save the latest one.
I have tried with useReducer and useState, but none of it seems to be working.
I am expecting to receive an object with the weekday name and an array with the hours:
Parent:
export const AvailabilityHours = ({
  register,
  setValue,
}: IAvailabilityHours) => {
  const { userDetails } = useUserDetails();

  const latestSessionId =
    userDetails?.availability?.[userDetails?.availability?.length - 1];

  const { data: sessionData, isLoading } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ['availabilitySession', latestSessionId],
    queryFn: () => getAvailabilitySession(latestSessionId),
    enabled: !!latestSessionId,
    retry: 3,
    retryDelay: 2000,
  });

  if (isLoading) {
    return <Loader />;
  }

  if (!sessionData) {
    return <Box p={5}>Nenhuma sessão disponível</Box>;
  }

  const { consultationDuration, weekdays } = sessionData;

  const dayHours = generateTimeSlots(consultationDuration || 60);

  return (
    <StyledIAvailabilityHoursBoxWrapper>
      <Box display='flex' justifyContent='flex-end' pb={2}>
        <Tooltip title='You can select a intire row by clicking on the first slot and dragging until the last one, but only horizontally'>
          <Help />
        </Tooltip>
      </Box>
      <StyledIAvailabilityGrid container spacing={2}>
        <WeekDaysHeader isSimple />
        <Grid container spacing={1} columns={8}>
          {dayHours.map((hour, index) => (
            <TimeSlotsRow
              key={`hour-${index}`}
              hour={hour}
              register={register}
              setValue={setValue}
              availableWeekdays={weekdays}
              dayHours={dayHours}
              isSimple
            />
          ))}
        </Grid>
      </StyledIAvailabilityGrid>
    </StyledIAvailabilityHoursBoxWrapper>
  );
};

Children:
export const TimeSlotsRow = ({
  hour,
  register,
  availableWeekdays,
  isSimple,
  setValue,
}: ITimeSlotsRow) => {
  const [selectedSlots, setSelectedSlots] = useState<SlotState[]>([]);

  useEffect(() => {
    register('selectedSlots');
  }, [register]);

  const weekDays = generateWeekDays();

  const isDayAvailable = (day: Date) => {
    const dayName = format(day, 'EEEE');
    return availableWeekdays.includes(dayName);
  };

  const slotIdFormat = (day: Date, time: string) => {
    const dayName = format(day, 'EEEE');
    return { dayName, time };
  };

  const isSlotSelected = (dayName: string, time: string) => {
    const day = [].find((d) => d.weekday === dayName);
    return day ? day.slots.includes(time) : false;
  };

  const handleSlotClick = (dayName: string, time: string) => {
    const updatedSlots = [...selectedSlots];

    const daySlotIndex = updatedSlots.findIndex(
      (slot) => slot.dayName === dayName
    );

    if (daySlotIndex > -1) {
      const daySlot = updatedSlots[daySlotIndex];

      if (daySlot.slots.includes(time)) {
        daySlot.slots = daySlot.slots.filter(
          (slotTime: string) => slotTime !== time
        );
      } else {
        daySlot.slots.push(time);
      }

      updatedSlots[daySlotIndex] = daySlot;
    } else {
      updatedSlots.push({ dayName, slots: [time] });
    }

    if (updatedSlots[daySlotIndex]?.slots.length === 0) {
      updatedSlots.splice(daySlotIndex, 1);
    }

    setSelectedSlots(updatedSlots);
    setValue('selectedSlots', updatedSlots);
  };

  return (
    <>
      <StyledHourColl item xs={1}>
        <HourCollWrapper>
          <Text variant='caption'>{hour}</Text>
        </HourCollWrapper>
      </StyledHourColl>
      {weekDays.map((day, index) => {
        const { dayName, time } = slotIdFormat(day, hour);
        const isCurrentDay = isToday(day);
        const dayAvailable = isDayAvailable(day);

        const isSelected = isSlotSelected(dayName, time);

        return (
          <StyledDaySlots key={`day-${index}`} item xs={1}>
            <SlotBox
              isSelected={isSelected}
              disabled={!dayAvailable}
              isCurrentDay={!isSimple && isCurrentDay}
              onClick={() => handleSlotClick(dayName, time)}
            />
          </StyledDaySlots>
        );
      })}
    </>
  );
};

Image_ 
Can you help me?
{ Monday: ['08:00', '09:00', ...], Wednesday: ['10:00'] }

Found the answer from a reddit post, where the user cleared my doubts using "Controller" from the same library.
https://www.reddit.com/r/reactjs/comments/1ff6igj/how_to_manage_time_slot_selection_for_weekdays/
